# Entity Framework row-level security per user

Tags: c#, entity-framework, security, dry

I'm working on ASP.Net MVC3 web-site with Entity Framework and SQL Server 2008 as a data storage. Also I'm using Repository pattern to concentrate all data-access code in one area.

In my application I have many users, every user can have many Projects. User should only have access to their own projects. 
At the moment I have this code:

```
    public IQueryable<Project> All
    {
        get { 
            return context.Projects
                .Where(p => p.Owner.ID == Util.GetCurrentUserID())
                .Select(p=>p); 
        }
    }

    public Project Find(System.Guid id)
    {
        return context.Projects
                .Where(p => p.Owner.ID == Util.GetCurrentUserID())
                .FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

If you noticed `.Where(p => p.Owner.ID == Util.GetCurrentUserID())` is duplicated. And I have quite a few other places where these exact conditions are littered.

Is there a way in DbContext to have this condition always appended automatically to any query going Projects table?

Something like:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Project> Projects
         .Where(p => p.Owner.ID == Util.GetCurrentUserID()) { get; set; }
}
```

OR

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get {
           // Insert a cast from IQuerieable to DBSet below
       return Projects
              .Where(p => p.Owner.ID == Util.GetCurrentUserID())
              .Select(p => p);
    } 
    set; }
}
```

**UPD** while writing the question, realised that the last version can just work - need to try out. Still would like to hear other options for code optimisation and making it more DRY.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you found your own solutioin, please post it as an answer, so people with the same problem can find help.

Comment: @rcdmk, surely I will. That's like a common theme here, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always write an extension method called "WhereProject". Then call the standard "Where" method in your extension method after appending your condition to your predicate.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereProject<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) where TSource: Project
{
     return source.Where(p=> p.Owner.ID == Util.GetCurrentUserID() && predicate);
}
```

You can skip predicate if you want or set it as null in the parameter list for default value and then act accordingly if you don't want to use predicate.

---

**This is probably what you want**, it is simple:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereProject<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) where TSource: Project
{
     return source.Where(p=> p.Owner.ID == Util.GetCurrentUserID());
}
```

**EDIT**
These solutions does not sound right to me. I think you would want to secure your row data one level higher, in my case it would be the **service layer**. Consider a method in your service class like this:

```
public List<Project> GetUserProjects(User user)
{
    return repo.All().Where(p => p.Owner.ID == Util.GetCurrentUserID()).ToList();
}
```

This way, from the method name, it is very clear what you are doing. It is not responsiblity of a repository to contain your specific logic. It is there to handle your data access only.

Comment: yeah, I thought about this approach. It is better then what I have at the moment, but not ideal - a programmer must remember to use WhereProject() in the query. It would be fantastic if I could specify these conditions one level higher.

Comment: hm.. that's actually what I'm trying to avoid - having another layer on top of repository. Repository is to handle data access only. Row security (imho) belongs to data acess. I understand that is very arguable point. I'll wait for another couple days and start a bounty - would like to hear other opinions on this matter.

Comment: rethinking your suggestion. I guess you are right, no logic should go in Repository: in case when I want to change data providers, logic will be screwed. I probably should have DataSecurity Layer that does that row filtering on select queries and adds bits of information on write.

Comment: After poking about for a while, reading different sources, I did come to conclusion that approach with Service layer is the best possible scenario.